# How do GraphQL arguments tie into fields?

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have read both the main "Learn" guide on [graphql.com](http://graphql.com) and the [howtographql.com](http://howtographql.com) tutorial.

I am still struggling with a few concepts, one of them is relating to Arguments.

Basically, I do not understand how GraphQL knows what field of an Object type, a passed argument in a Query type belongs to.

**Example:**

```
type Person {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  age: Int
  country: String!
}

type Query PersonsByAge {
  person(selectedCountry: String!): [Person]
}

query PersonsByAge {
  person(selectedCountry: 'Sweden')
}
```

**Questions**

1. How exactly does GraphQL know that the `selectedCountry` argument should filter on the `country` field?
2. Are there multiple instances of the Person Object type, like in normal OOP, **strong text**and these can be returned in a `List` as done above?
3. I am not entirely confident my syntax / code above is correct, are there any obvious mistakes?

I feel like I am missing something really basic here, I just found that the guides lacked depth and structure.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT:**

Fixed parenthesis typo, pointed out in Daniel's answer. Did not fix other syntax issues, to keep the answer matching the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Adding an argument or arguments for a particular field does not impact the value the field resolves to in itself. In GraphQL.js, every field has an associated `resolve` function (or "resolver"). It's up to the server to implement that function. The function receives four parameters, including the value of the parent field, the arguments for the field being resolved and the execution context. The resolver can use all or none of these parameters to determine the value that should be resolved for a field.
2. Yes, GraphQL includes a special collection type called `List` that "declares the type of each item in the List". These can be input or output types or scalars. In GraphQL.js, a List is effectively just an array. It's important to note that if a field's type is a List, it's resolver must return an array, and, likewise, if a field's type is an output type, the resolver cannot return an array. GraphQL will not coerce a `List` into a non-`List` value and vice-versa.
3. There's a couple of things wrong with your syntax. Your query has an extra parenthesis and no subselection for the `person` field (i.e. you don't specify the fields you want returned for that field, which is required since the type for the field is an output type, not a scalar). Additionally, in your schema definition, you've got an extraneous `PersonsByAge` label on your Query type which is invalid syntax and not really necessary.

Here's your example, reworked with correct syntax and a resolver to demonstrate the earlier point. This examples assumes you create your schema using `graphql-tools`.

```
const people = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Oscar', country: 'Sweden' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Sal', country: 'Italy' }
]
const typeDefs = `
  type Person {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    country: String!
  }
  type Query {
    person(id: ID!): Person
    people(selectedCountry: String!): [Person]
  }
`
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    person: (root, args, context) => {
      // this returns a single object
      return people.find(person => person.id === args.id)
    },
    people: (root, args, context) => {
      // this returns an array
      return people.filter(person => person.country === args.selectedCountry)
    },
  },
}
```

You may then query your schema client-side like this:

```
query SomeQueryName {
  people(selectedCountry: "Sweden") {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

I highly recommend checking out [Apollo Launchpad](https://launchpad.graphql.com/new), which will allow you to create a schema and query it on the fly so you can freely experiment with the syntax and learn by doing.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel. I really appreciate the detailed and thorough answer. I see now that the key lies in the resolver and it's arguments. Noen of the guides talked about that, and I guess that is because they want to be implementation agnostic. Anyways, terrific to know. A couple of follow-up questions, if I may: 1) I thought there are only really two types in GraqhQL: Object type (including custom object types and 3 specials object types: Query, Mutation, Subscription) and scalar type (including 5 built-in scalar types, Enumeration, and custom scalar types). How would you bucket it?

Comment: 2) Instead of graphql-tools and apollo-server-express, can't we just use graphql.js and express-graphql? GraphQL.js has the buildSchema function, perhaps making graphql-tools uneccessary? I am not too familiar with graphql-tools, I might have missed something.

Comment: 3) Do fields defined in a schema that return scalar types (Int, String, etc.) need to have resolvers implemented by us (the author) as well?

4) Regarding query names, is a name only used in the actual query, not in the definition? I read somewhere that if you define multiple queries they need names, i.e. cannot be anonymous. Did they then mean the query execution as opposed to the definition?

Comment: Those are good questions, and I'm fairly sure there's answers on SO to some of them. Might be worth a search. If not, they really should be posted as new, separate questions. Comments aren't really the right medium for this sort of thing. If you do post additional questions, I would also make sure you keep it to one question per question. Multi-question questions are likely to be closed.